# How to avoid Insert and Update conflict in SQL Server Merge Replication?

Tags: sql-server, merge-conflict-resolution, merge-replication

I have developed a web application using Asp.net Rest Api, Entity Framework code-first approach. I have publisher with 20-30 subscribers. All my subscribers may work online or offline. After setting up merge replication, I have faced insert and update conflicts.

The easiest way I have solved this problem using autonumber PK's is to change the autonumber increment from 1 to 10 (or 100, or 1000, whatever is required) then set the seed differently on all the participants. But this is not sufficient.

Kindly suggest a solution with a example.

Comment: You're gonna need to provide some code to get real help on StackOverflow. But you're saying that users can do "stuff" offline. I hope you don't create a "unique" id when being offline and then try to sync it to server - because that could cause some huge problems. But later it seems like you want to look into using Sequences possibly. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: The ID *must* be unique. The problem is caused precisely because you use a numeric primary key with identity. This means that any one of the subscribers can create the same ID. Either partition the ID range or use something truly unique like a sequential GUID, generated eg with `NEWSEQUENTIALID()`